# Display Oracle date in a given format with JSTL using Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp, datetime, oracle10g

I have a date field in a table in an Oracle(10g) database which is mapped by `TemporalType.TIMESTAMP` in Hibernate like,

```
@Column(name = "DISCOUNT_START_DATE")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date discountStartDate;

//Setter and getter.
```

It fetches dates and displays like the following (which are already inserted into the database),

```
2012-08-29 01:53:10.0
2012-08-20 02:32:22.0
2012-08-01 14:00:21.0
2012-08-20 13:58:01.0
2012-08-30 04:14:13.0
2012-09-10 16:13:45.0
```

When I attempt to display them using JSTL like,

```
<fmt:formatDate pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss" value="${row.discountStartDate}"/>
```

it throws an exception,

> javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert 2012-08-29 01:53:10.0 of type
>   class java.lang.String to class java.util.Date

I have tried to change `TemporalType.TIMESTAMP` to `TemporalType.DATE` but didn't work.

Earlier, it was working with XML mapping files (xxx.hbm.xml) like.

```
<property name="discountStartDate" type="date">
  <column length="7" name="DISCOUNT_START_DATE"/>
</property>
```

but with annotations, it failed. How to apply this format `dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss` to display those dates in JSP using JSTL?

---

**EDIT:**

The following is the `Discount` entity class which is mapped with the `DSCOUNT` table in Oracle (the `equals()` and the `toString()` methods have been omitted).

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DISCOUNT", catalog = "", schema = "WAGAFASHIONDB")
public class Discount  implements java.io.Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "DISCOUNT_ID", nullable = false, precision = 35, scale = 0)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "discountIdSequence", sequenceName = "DISCOUNT_SEQ", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "discountIdSequence")
    private Long discountId;

    @Column(name = "DISCOUNT_CODE", length = 100)
    private String discountCode;

    @Column(name = "DISCOUNT_PER", precision = 35, scale = 2)
    private double discountPer;

    @Column(name = "DISCOUNT_START_DATE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date discountStartDate;

    @Column(name = "DISCOUNT_END_DATE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date discountEndDate;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "discountId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<OrderTable> orderTableSet;

    public Discount() {
    }

    public Discount(Long discountId) {
        this.discountId = discountId;
    }

    public Long getDiscountId() {
        return discountId;
    }

    public void setDiscountId(Long discountId) {
        this.discountId = discountId;
    }

    public String getDiscountCode() {
        return discountCode;
    }

    public void setDiscountCode(String discountCode) {
        this.discountCode = discountCode;
    }

    public double getDiscountPer() {
        return discountPer;
    }

    public void setDiscountPer(double discountPer) {
        this.discountPer = discountPer;
    }

    public Date getDiscountStartDate() {
        return discountStartDate;
    }

    public void setDiscountStartDate(Date discountStartDate) {
        this.discountStartDate = discountStartDate;
    }

    public Date getDiscountEndDate() {
        return discountEndDate;
    }

    public void setDiscountEndDate(Date discountEndDate) {
        this.discountEndDate = discountEndDate;
    }

    public Set<OrderTable> getOrderTableSet() {
        return orderTableSet;
    }

    public void setOrderTableSet(Set<OrderTable> orderTableSet) {
        this.orderTableSet = orderTableSet;
    }
}
```

In JSP, the following loop is used to display data (reducing the code complexity).

```
<c:forEach var="row" items="${list}" varStatus="loop">
    <fmt:formatDate pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss" value="${row.discountStartDate}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

and in Spring DAO, the list which is iterated by the preceding loop is simply retrieved as follows.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Discount>getList(int currentPage, int rowsPerPage)
{
    List<Discount> list = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                          .createQuery("from Discount order by discountId desc")
                          .setFirstResult(currentPage)
                          .setMaxResults(rowsPerPage).list();

    for(Discount d:list)
    {
       System.out.println(d.getDiscountStartDate()+" : "+d.getDiscountEndDate());
    }
    return list;
}
```

The preceding loop is just for the sake of demonstration. It displays the dates from the table as follows.

```
2012-08-29 01:53:10.0 : 2012-08-31 01:53:16.0
2012-08-20 02:32:22.0 : 2012-08-24 02:34:36.0
2012-08-01 14:00:21.0 : 2012-08-31 14:01:30.0
2012-08-20 13:58:01.0 : 2012-08-21 13:58:20.0
2012-08-30 04:14:13.0 : 2012-11-23 16:21:57.0
2012-09-10 16:13:45.0 : 2012-10-26 16:13:39.0
2012-08-22 16:06:23.0 : 2012-08-15 16:06:17.0
2012-08-22 10:35:04.0 : 2012-08-17 10:34:56.0
2012-08-17 10:35:29.0 : 2012-08-10 10:35:35.0
2012-10-08 10:35:56.0 : 2013-03-08 10:35:49.0
```